# How to don't indent content frame when UITableView editing state

Tags: tableview

i don't want to indent content frame when UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone, can you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

i had solve this question:
  sorry,tableview have a delegate method:
     - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
return NO; will be ok.

But UITableViewCell also have a property: shouldIndentWhileEditing
it had no effect when i set NO, i don't know Why.